# Binary data stored in MySQL being corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, binary-data

I need to store 50 KiB - 500 KiB binary files (actually zlib compressed text files) in a MySQL database. Assuming that there is good reason to do this as opposed to just writing them to the filesystem, I am having troubles with the data being corrupted in the database. I have pulled it out with both PHP and Python, both show that the data is corrupted.

I had tried using PHP emulated prepared statements and non-emulated prepared statements to enter the data, as well as simply putting the data right in the query as if it were a string. All of these resulted in corrupt data.

With prepared statements:

```
$options = array('PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES' => FALSE);
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qb_cache;charset=utf8';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'hunter2', $options);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO cache (body) VALUES (:body)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':body', $body);
```

With emulated prepared statements:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qb_cache;charset=utf8';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'hunter2');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO cache (body) VALUES (:body)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':body', $body);
```

Straight into the database:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qb_cache;charset=utf8';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'hunter2');

$sql = "INSERT INTO cache (body) VALUES ('{$body}')";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Note that there is no PDO [PDO::PARAM_* constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) for binary data! By the way, I don't believe that I'm hitting the size limit for a MySQL field:

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 16777216 |
+--------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is what I get when I try to decode:

```
$ zlib-flate -uncompress < output_from_database
...snip...
74 ARP4s0B64R9P6oZOpe6262E}C k3A AFD001 Si IL4A57sflate: inflate: data: invalid block type


$ cat output_from_database | openssl zlib -d > decoded
140438369359520:error:29065064:lib(41):BIO_ZLIB_READ:zlib inflate error:c_zlib.c:570:zlib error:data error
```

Using Python to pull the data out of MySQL I see that the field is the right size, but I can't decompress it::

```
>>> pprint(zlib.decompress(row[0]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

Comment: There is [`PDO::PARAM_LOB`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php). Also what is column datatype?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: Thanks, that is a great find. The column type _was_ `blob` as for some reason I thought that `blob` was the largest datatype that MySQL supports. As it turns out, when I actually looked and saw that the size coming out of the database was 65535 bytes I understood that the data was being truncated. Moving to `longblob` resolved the issue.

Comment: There is NO good reason to do this as opposed to just writing them to the filesystem

Comment: Actually, sometimes there is. 1) Cloud computing where the database is automatically replicated across geographic regions but there is no 'canonical' server with a filesystem (not my current application, but I've seen them). 2) No write permissions to filesystem (again, not applicable now but I've seen it). 3) Simplifying or extant back up and versioning system (again, not my current situation). 4) Distributed computing (like the cloud computing, no single canonical filesystem). 5) Another reason, which _is_ my current situation :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: It wasn't me who downvoted your PDO answer (actually, I upvoted) even though I left a comment about a point of contention. In any case, it's a bit uncool to 'rep retaliate' even if you think that I've downvoted a post of yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the column type was `blob` as for some reason I thought that `blob` was the largest datatype that MySQL supports. As it turns out, when I actually looked and saw that the size coming out of the database was 65535 bytes I understood that the data was being truncated. **Moving to `longblob` resolved the issue.**

For the next guy: [MySQL Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).